# Android Circle Button with 4 stripes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to create a circle button in Android that has 4 diagonal stripes in it.

[image: Like This]

(Sorry for my poor photo editing skills.

The circle should be full and not cut off as shown.

Tried to use the layer-list and added a background button didn't work.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Post your drawable XML code here.

Comment: @FAT I have failed attempts on the drawable, non of them work. So far my drawable is simply a circle shape.

Comment: Make a FrameLayout and add a background drawable to it. Now that background drawable should be a xml file with properties set for circle. Now inside that FrameLayout set a ImageView to match_parent height and width . Make a SVG, import it as a vector drawable, use it to set src of that image. Or you can do is make a pattern png, make a drawable xml that uses that png as a tile, set that drawable as src to that imageview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** Create a custom `drawable` using `<layer-list>` and `<shape>` with `<rotate>` element.

**bg_striped_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />

            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- RED Stripe -->
    <item
        android:left="-200dp"
        android:bottom="100dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="140">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">

                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:width="40dp"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- GREEN Stripe -->
    <item
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:bottom="90dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="140">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">

                <size
                    android:width="200dp" />
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:width="40dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- BLUE Stripe -->
    <item
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="90dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="140">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">

                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:width="40dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- ORANGE Stripe -->
    <item
        android:top="140dp"
        android:bottom="-50dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="-50dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="140">

            <shape
                android:shape="line">

                <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                    android:width="40dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**2.** For circle shape, you can use 3rd party library [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) and set custom drawable `bg_striped_circle` using attribute `android:src="@drawable/bg_striped_circle"`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <!-- CIRCLE -->
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_striped_circle"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFF" />

    <!-- SQUARE -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_striped_circle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI**, I have used different stripe color for better understanding about custom drawable XML.

Hope this will help~

Comment: why can't we have first item in layer-list to have circle shape itself?